# Show only a part of an ItemsControl's source at first

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an ItemsControl displaying a collection of files. Those files are sorted by most recent modification, and there's a lot of them.

So, I want to initially only show a small part (say, only 20 or so) of them, and display a button labelled "Show More" that would reveal everything when clicked.

I already have a solution, but it involves using a good old LINQ `Take` on my view model's source property. I was wondering if there was a cleaner way.

Thanks.

Comment: `.Take()` seems fairly clean to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have the object that you assign to the ItemsSource handle this logic - on first assignment, it would report a limited subset of the items. When Show More is clicked, the object is updated to show more (or all entries) and then notifies the framework that the property has changed (e.g. using the IPropertyNotifyChanged).

```
public class MyItemSource
{
    private List<string> source = { ... };

    public MyItemSource()
    {
        this.ShowThisMany = 20;
    }

    public int ShowThisMany
    {
        get;
        set; // this should call\use the INotifyPropertyChanged interface
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> this[]
    {
        return this.source.Take(this.ShowThisMany);
    }
}

...
MyItemsSource myItemsSource = new MyItemsSource();
ItemsControl.Source = myItemsSource;
...

void OnShowMoreClicked(...)
{
    myItemsSource.ShowThisMany = 50;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you need to create some sort of 'view' on your data. There is nothing within the WPF framwork that will give you this functionality for free. In my opinion, a simple bit of Linq, `Take()`, is a clean and simple solution.